# Periodically autosave XHTML form input without using JavaScript (or any other script)?

Tags: xhtml

I just want to make sure, that I haven't missed something in the past years.

Today a customer pleaded me to find an autosaving solution, which works even if the user has disabled JavaScript in her browser.

I answered: "This is impossible", because afaik it is not possible at all, to periodically submit form input to a server using only XHTML, i.e. *without* the help of some scripting (e.g. using `setInterval()` and/or the `onunload` event).

Is it still impossible? Or is there s/t, I'm not aware of yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the data to the server, then having the user manually submit the form or using JavaScript is the only way (discounting less well supported scripting languages, or replacing the entire form with something that depends on a plug-in).

If you want protection against a browser crash without using JS, then you have to depend on the browser having the feature built in. You can't add it yourself.

In short: You are correct.